# AudioRecord producing gaps of zeroes on Android 5.01

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, zero, audiorecord

Using AudioRecord, I have attempted to write a test app to record a couple of seconds of audio to be displayed to the screen. However, I seem to get a repeating pattern of zero value regions as shown below. I'm not sure if this is normal behaviour or an error in my code.

[image: zeros]

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    private Button recordButton, playButton;
    private String filePath;
    private boolean recording;
    private AudioRecord record;
    private short[] data;
    private TestView testView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button recordButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myFrame);
        frame.addView(testView = new TestView(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.recordButton)
        {
            if(!recording)
            {
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(  SAMPLE_RATE,
                                                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                record = new AudioRecord(   MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                            SAMPLE_RATE,
                                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                            bufferSize * 2);

                data = new short[10 * SAMPLE_RATE]; // Records up to 10 seconds

                new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        recordAudio();
                    }

                }.start();

                recording = true;

                Toast.makeText(this, "recording...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                recording = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.playButton)
        {   
            testView.invalidate();
            Toast.makeText(this, "play/pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void recordAudio()
    {
        record.startRecording();
        int index = 0;
        while(recording)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int result = record.read(data, index, SAMPLE_RATE); // read 1 second at a time
            if(result == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION || result == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE)
            {
                App.d("SOME SORT OF RECORDING ERROR MATE");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                index += result; // increment by number of bytes read
                App.d("read: "+result);
            }
        }
        record.stop();
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, index);

        testView.setData(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

TestView.java

```
public class TestView extends View 
{
    private short[] data;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Path path = new Path();
    float min, max;

    public TestView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    }

    void setData(short[] data)
    {
        min = Short.MAX_VALUE;
        max = Short.MIN_VALUE;
        this.data = data;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            if(data[i] < min)
                min = data[i];

            if(data[i] > max)
                max = data[i];
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
        if(data != null)
        {
            float interval = (float)this.getWidth()/data.length;
            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i+=10)
                canvas.drawCircle(i*interval,(data[i]-min)/(max - min)*this.getHeight(),5 ,paint);

        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: your onDraw will have a problem if min==max.

Comment: I'm starting to think the read method returns the number of bytes instead of shorts. Also, is each 16bit sample put in one short or does it put 8 bits in one short and 8 bits in the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navigation bar icons make it look like you are probably running on Android 5, and there is a bug in the Android 5.0 release which can cause precisely the problem you are seeing.

Recording to shorts gave an erroneous return value on the L preview, and while substantially reworking the code in the course of fixing that they mistakenly doubled the offset argument in the 5.0 release.  Your code increments the index by the (correct) amount it has read in each call, but a pointer math mistake in the audio internals will double the offset you pass, meaning that each period of recording ends up followed by an equal period of unwritten-to buffer, which you see as those gaps of zeroes.

The issue was reported at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80866

A patch submitted at that time last fall was declined as they said they had already dealt with it internally. Looking at the git history for AOSP 5.1, that would appear to have been internal commit [283a9d9e1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/283a9d9e15e095493a7d9800667e49169143e7e3%5E%21/#F0) of November 13, which was not yet public when I encountered it later that month.  While I haven't tried this on 5.1 yet, it seems like that should fix it, so most likely it is broken from 5.0-5.02 (and in a different way on the L preview) but works correctly with 4.4 and earlier, as well as with 5.1 and later.

The simplest workaround for consistent behavior across broken and unbroken release versions is to avoid ever passing a non-zero offset when recording shorts - that's how I fixed the program where I encountered the problem.  A more complicated idea would be to try to figure out if you are on a broken version, and if so halve the passed argument.  One method would be to detect the device version, but it's conceivable some vendor or custom ROM 5.0 builds might have been patched, so you could go a step further and do a short recording with a test offset to a zeroed buffer, then scan it to see where the non-zero data actually starts.

Comment: I've been very unlucky with running into bugs with android. Thankyou, I'm running 5.01.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass half the offset to the read-function as suggested in the accepted answer. The offset is an integer and might be an uneven number. This will result in poor audio quality and would be incompatible to android versions other than 5.0.1. and 5.0.2. I used the following work-around, which works for all android versions. I changed:

```
short[] buffer = new short[frame_size*(frame_rate)]; 
num = record.read(buffer, offset, frame_size);
```

into

```
short[] buffer = new short[frame_size*(frame_rate)];
short[] buffer_bugfix = new short[frame_size]; 
num = record.read(buffer_bugfix, 0, frame_size);
System.arraycopy(buffer_bugfix, 0, buffer, offset, frame_size);
```

In words instead of letting the read-function copy the data to the offset position of the large buffer, I let the read-function copy the data to the smaller buffer. I then insert this data manually to the offset position of the large buffer.

Answer (score -1):

I can't check right now your code but I can provide you with some sample code you can test:

```
private static int channel_config = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static int format = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private static int Fs = 16000;
private static int minBufferSize; 
private boolean isRecording;
private boolean isProcessing;
private boolean isNewAudioFragment;

private final static int bytesPerSample = 2; // As it is 16bit PCM
private final double amplification = 1.0; // choose a number as you like
private static int frameLength = 512; // number of samples per frame => 32[ms] @Fs = 16[KHz]
private static int windowLength = 16; // number of frames per window => 512[ms] @Fs = 16[KHz]
private static int maxBufferedWindows = 8; // number of buffered windows => 4096 [ms] @Fs = 16[KHz]

private static int bufferSize = frameLength*bytesPerSample;
private static double[] hannWindow = new double[frameLength*bytesPerSample];

private Queue<byte[]> queue = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
private Semaphore semaphoreProcess = new Semaphore(0, true);

private RecordSignal recordSignalThread;
private ProcessSignal processSignalThread;

public static class RecorderSingleton {
    public static RecorderSingleton instance = new RecorderSingleton();
    private AudioRecord recordInstance = null;

    private RecorderSingleton() {
        minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(Fs, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        while(minBufferSize>bufferSize) {
            bufferSize = bufferSize*2;
        }
    }

    public boolean init() {
        recordInstance = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, Fs, channel_config, format, bufferSize);
        if (recordInstance.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            Log.d("audiotestActivity", "Fail to initialize AudioRecord object");
            Log.d("audiotestActivity", "AudioRecord.getState()=" + recordInstance.getState());
        }
        if (recordInstance.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int getBufferSize() {return bufferSize;}

    public boolean start() {
        if (recordInstance != null && recordInstance.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
            if (recordInstance.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED) {
                recordInstance.stop();
            }
            recordInstance.release();
        }
        if (!init()) {
            return false;
        }
        recordInstance.startRecording();
        return true;
    }
    public int read(byte[] audioBuffer) {
        if (recordInstance == null) {
            return AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION;
        }
        int ret = recordInstance.read(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        return ret;
    }
    public void stop() {
        if (recordInstance == null) {
            return;
        }
        if(recordInstance.getState()==AudioRecord.STATE_UNINITIALIZED) {
            Log.d("AudioTest", "instance uninitialized");
            return;
        }
        if(recordInstance.getState()==AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
            recordInstance.stop();
            recordInstance.release();
        }
    }
}

public class RecordSignal implements Runnable {
    private boolean cancelled = false;
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        // We're important...android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
        int bufferRead = 0;
        byte[] inAudioBuffer;
        if (!RecorderSingleton.instance.start()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            Log.d("audiotestActivity", "Recorder Started");
            while(isRecording) {
                inAudioBuffer = null;
                inAudioBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                bufferRead = RecorderSingleton.instance.read(inAudioBuffer);
                if (bufferRead == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION");
                } else if (bufferRead == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("read() returned AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE");
                }
                queue.add(inAudioBuffer);
                semaphoreProcess.release();
            }
        } 
        finally {
            // Close resources...
            stop();
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
    public void stop() {
        RecorderSingleton.instance.stop();
    }
    public void cancel() {
        setCancelled(true);
    }
    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }
    public void setCancelled(boolean cancelled) {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
    }
}

public class ProcessSignal implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
//android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        while(isProcessing) {
            try {
                semaphoreProcess.acquire();
                byte[] outAudioBuffer = new byte[frameLength*bytesPerSample*(bufferSize/(frameLength*bytesPerSample))];
                outAudioBuffer = queue.element();
                if(queue.size()>0) {
                    // do something, process your samples
                }
                queue.poll();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

and to start and stop simply:

```
public void startAudioTest() {
    if(recordSignalThread!=null) {
        recordSignalThread.stop();
        recordSignalThread.cancel();
        recordSignalThread = null;
    }
    if(processSignalThread!=null) {
        processSignalThread = null;
    }
    recordSignalThread = new RecordSignal();
    processSignalThread = new ProcessSignal();
    new Thread(recordSignalThread).start();
    new Thread(processSignalThread).start();
    isRecording = true;
    isProcessing = true;
}

public void stopAudioTest() {
    isRecording = false;
    isProcessing = false;
    if(processSignalThread!=null) {
        processSignalThread = null;
    }
    if(recordSignalThread!=null) {
        recordSignalThread.cancel();
        recordSignalThread = null;
    }
}
```